# How to pass Jwt Token in python for request.get()

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, jwt

Not able to pass authentication key correctly.

I am trying to perform requests.get() using token, have tried multiple way to pass the argument but no luck so far.

```
import requests
import json

myToken = 'ABCD'  #(Dummy token, have copied actual token from session storage in chrome)
myUrl ='http://10.197.194.137/'

head = {'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(myToken) +myToken}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.get(url = myUrl,headers=head)

pastebin_url = response.text 

print(pastebin_url);
```

> Error :  **Description:** An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Kindly explain best practice of using authentication using Token.

Comment: The error message isn't helpful in this case, as it just says it can't show the actual error. Are you able to follow the instructions given in the error message and provide the real error message here?

Comment: IMO, I am not able to authenticate and that is the root cause of this error message. Here I am just trying to pass Token and authenticate my session. Not sure how to debug using HTML error.

Comment: add `print(head)` to your code, then you can see how it actually looks like. The token is doubled and everything in quotes. Ususally an authorization header looks like this: `Authorization: Bearer <yourToken>.`  or  `Authorization: JWT <yourToken>`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked!! Now I am getting response as "{"Message":"Ihre Anfrage ist nicht mehr gültig. Bitte melden Sie sich erneut an!"} Eng: 
{"Message": "Your request is no longer valid, please sign in again!"}.
". How I can do it correctly, I am log in to the application using token and navigate through JSON ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```py
head = {'Authorization': 'token {}'.format(myToken) +myToken}
```

is probably wrong.

- You append `myToken` *twice*.
- The value of the `Authorization` header should be `Bearer ${myToken}`.

Do this:

```py
head = {'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(myToken)}
```

Comment: One minor change in code and now I am able to retrieve data using API call. ```head = {'Authorization': '{}'.format(myToken)}```

Comment: If this works the server accepting this JWT is wrong. The header must be `Authorization: Bearer ${JWT}`. It is wrong to omit the `Bearer`. Check with the server.

Comment: I don't understand your question and I have no idea why a server might send(?) you such a JSON object. The value of `jwtToken` in this JSON is a valid JWT but it contains no claims.  You can check this at https://jwt.io/.

Comment: Many JWT based implementations also use `X-Auth-Token` header and the value of that header does not have any additional `Bearer` or a space after it. This might also be the possibility that token is being not recognized by the server.